# Splitting up a field based on the number of iterations within the field R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a piece of code that breaks out the variable Ids from a variable_id field, the count of variables can change depending on the experiment. In the sample below i have 5 different variables. I would like to get a function that would check the number of variables in the variation_id field (the number of variables is the count of numerical blocks separated by '_') in order to tell R to run the code below a set number of time.

I looked at loops but didn't find a good way to do this.
Thanks.

```
data$variable_1<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",1)
data$variable_2<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",2)
data$variable_3<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",3)
data$variable_4<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",4)
data$variable_5<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",5)

variation_id
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1073930921_1032241802_1044434085_1068913167
1048852146_1068950941_1041087796_1044434085_1048407737
1048852146_1068950941_1041087796_1044434085_1048407737
1048852146_1068950941_1041087796_1044434085_1048407737
1048852146_1068950941_1041087796_1044434085_1048407737
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len <- length(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id), split="\\_"))

for(i in 1:len){
  data[[paste0("variable_", i)]] <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variation_id),"\\_"),"[",i))
}
```